# import a go module created using swig

Tags: c++, go, swig

I just picked up swig in an attempt to port a large [library](https://github.com/LibRaw/LibRaw) written in C++, to golang. The build and install went okay, and now I'd like to test it by using it in another project I'm working on. I built the module in a separate swig directory at the root of the library directory, and pushed a fork of the library with the swig changes to my own repo. The structure then looks like this

```
.
├── bin
├── buildfiles
├── doc
├── GoPro
├── internal
├── lib
├── libraw
├── m4
├── object
├── RawSpeed
├── RawSpeed3
├── samples
├── src
└── swig
      ├── go.mod
      ├── libraw.go
      ├── libraw.i
      ├── libraw_c_api.cxx
      └── libraw_wrap.c
```

The module name in the `swig/go.mod` file is `github.com/MRHT-SRProject/LibRawGo`.
I tried to include the module in another project but it failed with the error `module github.com/MRHT-SRProject/LibRawGo@latest found (v0.0.0-20221005050554-bc562f90d08d), but does not contain package github.com/MRHT-SRProject/LibRawGo`. I am assuming it has to do with the module being a sub folder of the project, but I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that go is expecting a sub-folder within the module with the same package name as the module defined within swig. By renaming the swig directory to the name given to the module I got it working.